# Popup to Present Application

Tags: popup

I have an donate application script that has all its files in one Folder called **donation**.

The **donation** folder has within it the following types:

```
A Folder named paypal_integration_class
config.php
connect.php
donate.php
thankyou.php
styles.css
```

I seek to facilitate access to the Donate application from a **Support** link on the navigation bar which will present the application to the visitor in a pop up window.

Calling the application using the following popup function:

```
function popup() {window.open('donation/donate.php',    '','scrollbars=1,statusbar=0,resizable=0,width=650,height=580,left=450,top=80');}
```

The donate.php file renders correctly as required in the popup, when called from the navigation.

Can the other .php, .css and File Folder that exists inside the **donation** Folder be written into the following popup script:-

**function popup() {window.open('donation/donate.php', '','scrollbars=1,statusbar=0,resizable=0,width=650,height=580,left=450,top=80');}**

Comment: yes you could, CSS can be embedded within donate.php, and your process and action can as well

Comment: in donate.php you could have relative `includes` for each as well

Comment: I have worked this popup thing in the past to present single page applications like a 'Contact Form' or a 'Send link to a Friend' and it worked successfully. The current donate application has a number of files and a folder and presents a step up in the level of experience required to achieve a working application. I am a bit of a newbie and this leaves me pushing at the boundaries to get in. Could you please expand on: the includes for each as well and embedding the CSS file in the donate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in donate.php you could place reference to http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

```
 include 'config.php';
 include 'connect.php';


?>
```

for the embedded css you would for example in the `head` of your html just

```
 <style type="text/css">
 body {font-color:#222222;} ..... 
 </style>
```

and as for the `thankyou.php` that could be in the same page you would pass/set the `return
page from paypay to the same`donate.php?action=thankyou`page or`thankyou.php` as its self

Comment: yeah good to here, i can do a test as well if you need a hand, you realy need to encrypt you button, or add a hash so people cant tamper with your values, example they could debit form you

Comment: Aah,encryption is probably another steep learning curve! Adding a hash seems like a good idea - how is same achieved. Nothing in the test position to debit from. Switched test position back to demo mode. I have used the same approach to the popup on the support link that I used on the Tell a Friend link but I get from my computer a 500 server error.

Comment: i saw that error, did you move the `donate.php` to the live website directory? For the encrypted button here is a link for future reference http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php

Comment: i dont know if you can go in to the SO chat because you dont have anuf points, if you can you should and i could explain more. where not ment to have extend conversation in the comments.